# (IronPython Studio) Where is the console?

Tags: .net, ironpython

I am new to IronPython. I've read the MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300810.aspx and for what I've understood I can set code with IronPython on the run. I created a simple Windows Forms project in IronPython studio and ran it, but I can't find on the IDE anywhere to type code into. Isn't it possible, am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Go ask the dev's that wrote it... Not programming.

Answer (score 1):

IronPython isn't supported by default in Visual Studio, you have to first download and install IronPython Studio ( http://www.codeplex.com/IronPythonStudio ) then you'll have the option of creating Python projects directly in Visual Studio.

Also I'd recommend you check out SharpDevelop ( http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/ ), it is mostly compatible with Visual Studio solutions and project files and has built-in support for Ironpython projects.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want an interactive IronPython shell, there are two ways to get it:

1. Open windows explorer. Go to the directory where IronPython is installed. Run ipy.exe
2. Start > run > cmd. cd into the directory where IronPython is installed. Now, just type ipy . To get back to the normal command line, type exit()

Both these ways are essentially the same, but work well. I normally use the second method and have had no trouble thus far...

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, there is an icon in the start menu somewhere, under the IronPython folder. It launches a command line with IronPython loaded, so I'm sure there's other ways to start it, too.

Comment: Yes, but that is not in ironpython studio.